# Question on change of variables during convolution/correlation

Tags: terminology, summation, convolution, correlation

I am trying to understand how the following two statements are equivalent:

$$
\sum_{l=-\infty}^{\infty} h^*[l] \ R_{xx}[m+l] = \sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty} h^*[i-m] \ R_{xx}[i]
$$

I get that we made $m + l = i$, and plug this into the $h$ and $R_{xx}$. What I do not get is how the sigma on the right hand side is now all the sudden going from $i$, and not $i-m$. What happened to the $m$?

What is the rule on changing variables like this within summations?

Comment: What happens if you replace $m+l$ by $i$ so that $l$ becomes $i-m$, and as $l$ varies from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$, $m+l$ varies from $m-\infty$ to $m+\infty$?

Comment: @DilipSarwate I guess $i$ varies from $m-\infty$ to $m+\infty$... I guess I do not understand the "asymmetry" of why we chose to put $i$ into the RHS sigma, and not say, $m$. My understanding is blurry here...

Comment: @DilipSarwate I thought more about this but I still do not get your question... :-/

Comment: In the summation on the left, $m$ is just a constant, and after the sum has been computed, we note that the value depends on $m$. Similarly for the function on the right. You are never summing on $m$ on either side and so it should not appear as the index of summation; in fact, why not put $m=5$, say, and then identify the term in the right-side sum that corresponds to $h^*[l]R_{xx}[l+5]$ in the sum on the left. Hints: $i = l+5$, $i-5=l$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Ok right... $m$ should never be in the summation because we never sum on $m$. Ok that makes sense. If I put $m=5$ as you mention, then the RHS will become: $\sum_{i-5 = -\infty}^{i-5 = \infty} h^*[i-5] \ R_{xx}[i]$... right?

Comment: @DilipSarwate And so based on this now, since $i - 5 = -\infty$, we can of course move the 5 over, and so it effectively becomes $i = -\infty$? Have I understood correctly?